# Disadvantage of using Reflection in android?

Tags: java, android, reflection, notifications, led

To implement things like canceling calls, clearing missed call notifications ,disabling notification LED and other such complex functionalities I have to rely heavily on Reflection. Will it effect my app in a long run?

Comment: in which way could it afflicts your app?

Comment: You need to be a whole lot more specific. It's impossible to answer such a general question with anything more than "reflection can be slow, do it several times a second and you app might feel sluggish".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main disadvantages of refelections are

**It is Slow**

reflection involves types that are dynamically resolved, certain Java virtual machine optimizations can not be performed. Consequently, reflective operations have slower performance than their non-reflective counterparts, and should be avoided in sections of code which are called frequently in performance-sensitive applications.

**Fragile**

Reflective code is more fragile in the face of API changes.

**Security Issues**

You can't allow non-trusted code to use reflection.

**Testing Problems**

More thorough testing and debugging is required because you are replacing compile-time type checking with run-time type checking.

**Exposure of Internals**

By using reflection you can access private class members which are not permitted to use using non reflection methods. the use of reflection can result in unexpected side-effects, which may render code dysfunctional and may destroy portability.

In your cases I think the problems should be, slow, fragile and testing problems
If the above problems don't bother you then you are free to use reflections in your app.

[link1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459345/disadvantages-advantages-of-reflection),[link3](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/170778/why-is-javas-reflection-package-considered-the-dark-side-of-the-force)